# In need of some aid in regards to making my code more efficient

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I've created a form that gathers and submits information to SQL database via LINQ, and sends an email if all goes while saving the database and doing a redirect. Recently, it started submitting data and calling errors (thread aborts) within the submit function, which seemed unusual. I solved it by using Boolean flags, and all works well. Looking over my code now, I am quite sure I can make it more efficient.  I am seeking advice on this.

My biggest concern is handling the exceptions correctly, and not having unnecessary code, but efficient code.

Below is a basic overview of the backend of my form:

```
public partial class myClass : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private regEntities _reg = new regEntities();
    private const string _formName = "Form Name";
    private Boolean dbError = false;
    private Boolean transError = false;
    private Exception ce;
    private Exception st;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        Session["FormName"] = _formName;
    }
    private void Initialize()
    {
        FormHelpers.GenerateStates(ddlState);
        FormHelpers.GenerateCountries(ddlCountry);
    }
    private void CreateEntry()
    {
        try
        {
            diploma dip = new diploma();

            dip.ssn = txtStudID.Text;
            dip.fname = txtFirstName.Text;
            dip.mname = txtMi.Text;
            dip.lname = txtLastName.Text;
            dip.city = txtCity.Text;
            dip.state = ddlState.SelectedItem.Text;
            dip.country = ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Text;
            dip.email = txtEmail.Text;
            dip.grad_year = txtGYear.Text;
            dip.grad_term = ddlGterm.SelectedItem.Text;
            dip.degree = ddlSDegree.SelectedItem.Text;
            dip.submit_date = DateTime.Now;

            _registrar.AddTotables(dip);
            _registrar.SaveChanges();

        }
        catch (Exception oe)
        {
            dbError = true;
            ThrowDbError(oe);
        }
    }
    private void ThrowDbError(Exception oe)
    {
        _registrar.Dispose();
        Session.Contents.Add("FormException", oe);
        Response.Redirect("/Database-Error/", true);
    }

    private void SendAdminMail(string addresses, string submitter)
    {
        var fromAddress = new MailAddress("webserv@usi.edu");
        var recips = new MailAddressCollection();
        var splitAddresses = addresses.Split(',');

        foreach (var splitAddress in splitAddresses)
        {
            recips.Add(new MailAddress(splitAddress.Trim()));
        }

        string subject = "Readmit New Entry";


        const string adminSection = "https://www.mywebsite.com/admin/";

        var bodytext = new StringBuilder();
        bodytext.Append("<html><body>");
        bodytext.AppendFormat("<h2>{0} Form Submission</h2>", _formName);
        bodytext.AppendFormat("<p>Submitted by <strong>{0}</strong> at <strong>{1}</strong></p>", submitter,
                              DateTime.Now);
        bodytext.AppendFormat(
            "<p>Please check your administration section located at <a href='{0}'>{0}</a> for complete details of the submission</p>",
            adminSection);
        bodytext.Append("</body></html>");

        Mail.SendMail(recips, fromAddress, subject, bodytext, true);
    }

    protected void FormSubmit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Validate();
        if (!Page.IsValid)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (dbError == false)
        {
            try
            {
                CreateEntry();
                SendAdminMail("email@email.com", txtFirstName.Text + " " + txtLastName.Text);
                Response.Redirect("/thank-you", true);
            }
            catch (Exception oe)
            {
                transError = true;
                st = oe;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ThrowDbError(st);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I don't see `transError` used anywhere; it's set once but not evaluated.  Regarding `dberror`, is there any reason you can't catch different exceptions within `FormSubmit()` rather than using these four fields?  Your `SendAdminMail()` probably doesn't throw any `SqlException`s, after all.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades I notices transError does nothing and actually removed it. In the FormSubmit I was trying to figure out how to make this more efficient. I cant think of any other exceptions at all though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason you can't do it the easy way?

```
protected void FormSubmit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    Page.Validate();
    if (!Page.IsValid)
        return;

    try
        {
        CreateEntry();
        SendAdminMail("email@email.com", txtFirstName.Text + " " + txtLastName.Text);
        Response.Redirect("/thank-you", true);
        }
    catch (Exception ex)
        {
        ThrowDbError(ex);
        Response.Redirect("/error", true);
        }
    }
```

If you want to handle certain exceptions more specifically, the "right" way to do it is with additional `catch` blocks for the exceptions which need special handling (e.g., `SqlException`).  Offhand I don't see why you'd want to; since this is a web app, my inclination would be to dump any exception to a log (or e-mail it to an admin) but offer only generic output to the user, to avoid exposing implementation details.

I may be missing something.  Was there a specific reason you used that bool-and-if pattern?

Comment: Well I was getting a Thread Abort Error and it sent it to our error page. However it still submitted to the database and sent the email

Comment: If that error happens during `CreateEntry()` then, in my model, execution will jump to the `catch` block and the e-mail will not be sent.  Is that what you're trying to achieve?  Ensuring that the e-mail is not sent if the database action fails?

Comment: Yes that is the intention, however there is no error in the CreateEntry(), everything is added successfully to the database and the email sent successfully

Comment: OK, then what *is* the method which is throwing exceptions?

Comment: I believe it is the createEntry()